# get string in input and print it folded in C

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, c-strings, getchar

I'm trying to write a program which gets one or more input lines, and if one line is too long, it gets folded at a maximum number of chars. My approach would be to write the input chars in a first array, of a given length. If Maximum length is reached or `'\n'` as input, i copy the content in a bigger array which will be the final string to print and get the second line in input. Problem is: it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Thanks for the help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXCOL 10
#define FINAL_LENGTH 300
char line[MAXCOL];
char final_string[FINAL_LENGTH];
extern int fnlstr_pos = 0;
int main() 
{
    int pos, c;
    pos = 0;
    while(c=getchar() != EOF)
    {
        line[pos] = c;

        if (pos + 1 >= MAXCOL || c == '\n'){
            to_printandi(pos);
            pos = 0;
        }
        ++pos;

    }
    printf("%s", final_string);


}


to_printandi(pos)
int pos;
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i <= pos; ++i){
        final_string[fnlstr_pos] = line[i]; 
        ++fnlstr_pos;
    }
    if (final_string[fnlstr_pos] != '\n'){
        final_string[++fnlstr_pos] = '\n';
    }
    ++fnlstr_pos;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" expresses nothing of value.  Provide example input, intended behavior, and actual behavior please.

Comment: `c=getchar() != EOF` is the same as `c=(getchar() != EOF)`, which is not what you want

Comment: `to_printandi(pos) int pos; {` Don't you have a compiler available that is from this millennium? This K&R style should not be used unless you have an ancient compiler not able to understand any of the C standards released since 1989. Any decent (and recent) compiler should also tell you that you should provide a prototype for that function before calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems in the code. Others have already pointed out the bug in the `getchar()` line.

More variables and more functions and more code only twist one around in knots. If you take some time to think about what you want to achieve, go slowly, you can get your results with much less effort. Less code full of helpful comments, make for better programs.

**EDIT**
Looking at code with fresh eyes, I realised that the two lines explicitly setting the 'trailing' byte to '\0' were write 0 overtop of bytes already initialised to 0. Have commented out those two lines as they are superfluous.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char buf[ 1024 ] = { 0 }; // buffer initialised
    int ch, cnt = 0, ccnt = 0; // input char and counters

    while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF ) { // get a character
        ccnt++; // count this character
        buf[ cnt++ ] = (char)ch; // assign this character
        // buf[ cnt ] = '\0'; // string always terminated
        if( buf[ cnt-1 ] == '\n' ) // user supplied LF?
            ccnt = 0; // reset the counter (for width)
        else
        if( ccnt == 10 ) { // reached max output width?
            buf[ cnt++ ] = '\n'; // inject a LF
            // buf[ cnt ] = '\0'; // string always terminated
            ccnt = 0; // reset the counter (for width)
        }
    }
    puts( buf ); // output the whole shebang

    return 0;
}
```

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnop
qrs
tuv
wxyz
^D // end of input
0123456789
abcdefghij
klmnop
qrs
tuv
wxyz
```

Like the OP code, this does not test for overrunning the buffer. An easy addition left as an exercise for the reader.

---

**EDIT2:**
Then again, why have a buffer to overrun?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main( void ) {
    for( int ch, n = 0; ( ch = getchar() ) !=  EOF; /**/ )
        if( (n = putchar( ch ) == '\n' ? 0 : n + 1) == 10 )
            putchar( '\n' ), n = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is very smart and a pleasure to read. I'll try to do the overrun test.

Comment: This is the best answer as it's thoroughly detailed and deserves to go to the top. If I had to rewrite the problem, I wonder if it would be a good idea to use `getline()` instead of `getchar()`?

Comment: @JardelLucca Thank you... (blush)... There are countless ways to do this sort of thing. The input is buffered, anyway, so this one-char-at-a-time isn't so terrible (imho). Lots of ways to skin a cat! `:-)` (I look at it again and realise the 2 lines "setting terminator" are pointless. Only depositing chars into a buffer full of '\0', anyway... Oh, well... `:-)` )

Comment: @JardelLucca On second thought, `getline()` wouldn't be quite so nice (imho). One would need to deal with that line buffer (free after use?) in addition to transcribing up to 'n' chars to another buffer to inject the '\n' if necessary... I like "less code" when possible. `:-)`

Comment: Yeah exactly, "less code" is what I meant! Sometimes the most important requisite is performance or other thing. Maybe using `fgets()` passing `n` as the maximum length would kill two bird with one stone. It's kind of overthinking but SO is possibly the only way I can learn/discuss these things as code reviews in companies never seem to get that good as SO comments hehe

Comment: @JardelLucca When CPUs ran with clock speeds of kHz, performance was an issue. Unless you're writing OS code or server stuff for Google, making a user wait 0.0003 seconds less for a response is, imo, a waste of time. Will the user use the code the about a million times to balance the life-seconds lost in 4hrs of "optimising", shaving off a few nanoseconds? Almost as important as correct, clear & concise is "practicality". `:-)`

Comment: @JardelLucca Re: `fgets()`... In this instance, that would entail the OS having a buffer called 'stdin', the function having a buffer to pass to 'fgets()' for filling, and another buffer to transcribe into (injecting LF where needed.) `getchar()` eliminates one of those buffers. It's all much the same, really... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 excellent points! As a joke though I'd also argue that using more syscalls/standard functions has the advantage of allowing me to tell my manager the fallacious argument that my algorithm is slow because it's the OS fault for being slow

Comment: @JardelLucca This talk about I/O buffering... Got me re-thinking... New version posted here... `:-)`

Comment: @Fe2O3 I think this latest version is as good as it can get. It changes the behavior a little bit, but it doesn't matter as it could well be piped to another program. Would never thought about modifying "business logic" for such a small program. Considering requirements change should always be the first step. That's an art of its own...

Comment: @JardelLucca What is "good"? That last one does have a problem when a LF occurs exactly at a boundary... The behaviour should be explored and the requirements clarified. Typical of any programming problem; client says "round the value" but cannot understand there are 3 options for rounding (up/down/to nearest)... You do what you can... Sometimes that is making the "executive decision" on your own, aware that others will criticise you for whichever decision you make... _C'est la guerre_... Cheers! `:-)` (Sometimes it's best to program for all possibilities... Hahaha!)

Comment: @Fe2O3 so true! Still worse is when you are asked to provide a solution for which the modeled problem only exists in the mind of the requester, such as when they don't understand current system behavior very well LOL

Answer (score 1):

This question is very broad and it would helpful if you said what the problem is but I can see one issue -- you don't null terminate the final_string variable.  add

```
final_string[fnlstr_pos] = '\0';
```

before the printf.

Maybe that fixes the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

For starters this statement

```
while(c=getchar() != EOF)
```

is equivalent to

```
while( c = ( getchar() != EOF ) )
```

So c is always equal to1 if EOF is not encountered.

You need to write

```
while( ( c=getchar() ) != EOF)
```

And you need to append the input sequence with the terminating zero character '\0' tp form a string.

Another problem is these code snippet with for loop

```
for(i = 0; i <= pos; ++i){
    final_string[fnlstr_pos] = line[i]; 
    ++fnlstr_pos;
}
```

As within the loop the variable `fnlstr_pos` was increased then this if statement

```
if (final_string[fnlstr_pos] != '\n'){
    final_string[++fnlstr_pos] = '\n';
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because the variable points to a non-initialized element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is here:

```
while(c=getchar() != EOF)
```

Given the operator precedence, this will result in the same as:

```
while(c= (getchar() != EOF))
```

So `c` will be `1` (true) inside the loop.

Change this to:

```
while((c=getchar()) != EOF)
```

This is the main problem. Just as @Hogan suggested, there are other issues such as not null terminating the strings.
As you declare them global, they will be zeroed so you can get away with that though not in the case the user provides a string with maximum length.

Also it would greatly improve the code if you could use string manipulation functions from `<string.h>` instead of copying byte by byte.